# Can i do the effect shown in this page using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please look at this page:

http://www.nike.com/nikeos/p/nikegolf/en_US/

In the slide number 2, there is a midpanel that does a growing effect onmouse over.Some panels step aside at the same time or simply grows over another. As you can see, the background changes, the box grows as well as its content. I think that is flash, but, is there a way to obtian the same results using jquery? I have certain jquery experience but i dont wich function would be usefull to combine to get those results

Thanks

Comment: What effect are you talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is flash but if you want to do some thing like it try

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

I did a flash like effect for a customer using `.animate()` it can look very good using images for each part.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the animate() function.

firstly, i would make sure the elements like those menu elements are all set to be variable width/height.  then, make an onmouseover event handler which is tied to your animate function which will increase or decrease the size of the element that is being moused over. since all the elements are variable width/height, they will adjust based on the amount of space available to them. you probably will want to have a short animation time.

research animate and if you have any more questions post here.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily, because the image itself is being animated. This is not just html object manipulation.